# How do I go about designing a background image for a responsive website?

Tags: responsive-design, background-image

I've been looking around all day for an answer or a guide but I can't seem to find anything. I may be missing a key word here.

I have a single page website that I would like to design a background image for in photoshop. I would like to be able to design this image around the elements on the webpage. This wouldn't be too hard to design for one specific screen size, but the positioning of elements and the width of the screen can change dramatically from device to device. I only have two ideas of how to go about this, neither of which seems like a good method:

1. Create a background image that ignores elements on the page and doesn't have too much detail on the right/left to get chopped off on mobile devices.
2. Create a separate background image for each device size and use media queries to load the correct image.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Here is an example screenshot of the kind of background I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets address this: "How do I go about designing a background image for a responsive website?"

Obviously, there are more than one correct answers to this question. The simplest solution (IMO) would be to create a high-res image that is abstract and thus won't appear amiss if parts of it are chopped off as screen size becomes smaller. The background image on the site you posted is using this method. The wood paneling results in a design that is irrelevant to screen size.